# Stange behavior when using Get-ADGroups and Get-ADGroupMember in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am running into a strange issue when using Get-ADGroups and Get-ADGroupMembers

This line works correctly (no issues)

```
$searchFilter = "OU=Projects,DC=my,DC=lab"

Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $distinguishedName | Get-ADGroupMember | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | Get-ADUser | ft Name, SamAccountName, Enabled
```

However this block does not work

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $distinguishedName 

foreach ($g in $groups) {
    Write-Host "Group:" $g.CN "(" $g.DistinguishedName ")"

        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $g.DistinguishedName -Debug -Verbose | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | Get-ADUser | ft Name, SamAccountName, Enabled
}
```

Returns the following exception

```
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException: An operations error occurred ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[schemas.microsoft.com._2008._1.ActiveDirectory.CustomActions.GetADGroupMemberFault]: Active Directory returned an error processing the operation.
```

Anyone have any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 0):

Your second one works for me. Double-check your $distinguishedName value that you are passing to `-SearchBase`.

I noticed that you define $searchFilter, but you never actually reference it. Is that a typo?

Comment: Its the same searchFilter for both -- so if the 1st code works and the 2nd doesn't it would seem there is something wrong in the underlying type system?

Comment: Where are you referencing the variable $searchFilter? You define it, but you never reference it after that.